# QTreeView, class, arguments, instance and attributes

Tags: python, class, pyqt, instance, qtreeview

I get to POO, python and PyQt slowly and I have a problem to understand something about passing argument and attributes.

I found online a code  dealing with QTreeView (see below) and I don't understand how Index is passed into showPath(). Also why self.filename and self.filepath are not passed to the instance?

I hope I am clear enough ... Thank a lot.

```
from PyQt4           import QtGui
class TreeViewWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
def __init__(self, parent=None):

    super(TreeViewWidget, self).__init__(parent)                
    self.model = QtGui.QFileSystemModel(self)
    self.model.setRootPath(rootpath)
    self.indexRoot = self.model.index(self.model.rootPath())

    self.treeView = QtGui.QTreeView(self)
    self.treeView.setExpandsOnDoubleClick(False)
    self.treeView.setModel(self.model)
    self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.indexRoot)
    self.treeView.setColumnWidth(0,220)
    self.treeView.clicked.connect(self.showPath)
    self.treeView.doubleClicked.connect(self.openQuickLook)

    self.labelFileName = QtGui.QLabel(self)
    self.labelFileName.setText("File Name:")

    self.lineEditFileName = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)

    self.labelFilePath = QtGui.QLabel(self)
    self.labelFilePath.setText("File Path:")

    self.lineEditFilePath = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)

    self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.labelFileName, 0, 0)
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEditFileName, 0, 1)
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.labelFilePath, 1, 0)
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEditFilePath, 1, 1)

    self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
    self.layout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.treeView)

def givePathName(self, index):

    indexItem = self.model.index(index.row(), 0, index.parent())

    self.filename = self.model.fileName(indexItem)
    self.filepath = self.model.filePath(indexItem)

def showPath(self, index):

    self.givePathName(index)
    self.lineEditFileName.setText(self.filename)
    self.lineEditFilePath.setText(self.filepath)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand how `index` is passed into `showPath()`

You connect the widget's click signal to `showPath` explicitly:

```
self.treeView.clicked.connect(self.showPath)
```

part of this signal is the `index` of the specific item clicked on; this is passed as an argument to `showPath` automatically.

> Also why `self.filename` and `self.filepath` are not passed to the instance?

They are *instance attributes*, they belong to the instance and are accessible to all methods of that instance. They are created in `givePathName()`, and are then part of the `TreeViewWidget` instance object. They start with `self.` because that is, by convention, the name given to the instance in instance methods (and the implicit first argument to those methods).

Putting that together:

```
def showPath(self, index):
           # ^ the instance object, so you can access its attributes
                 # ^ the index of the specific item clicked
```

Answer (score 1):

The `clicked` signal of your QTreeView pass the `QModelIndex` of the item clicked as an argument to any connected slots.

See [Qt Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#clicked) and [PyQt signal and slots documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html).